# Can ECDSA keys hashing to a contract address be used to sign a transaction?

Tags: private-key, ecdsa

Theoretical question: say I randomly managed to get a private key that provides a pubic key that hashes to and address that happens to be already in use **for a contract instead of being an EOA**.

Does this mean I would be able to sign transactions as if I was the owner of that address (contract)?

Maybe related to this: although I understand the cryptographic process behind the signature, I have not managed to figure if there is any kind of safeguard in the EVM blockchains that prevents an address with code in it (a contract) to initiate and sign a transaction. Does it only rely on the limitation (that is now being discussed due to account abstraction, [see here](https://hackmd.io/@matt/r1neQ_B38)) that there is no way for a contract to initiate the tx?

Comment: See this https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/138191/75850

Answer (score 0):

you are basically asking: did the Ethereum team validate for a possible bug of sending a Tx from a contract account? and the answer is , yes they did.

the function is called `preCheck` , here is the snippet:

```
    // Make sure the sender is an EOA
    if codeHash := st.state.GetCodeHash(st.msg.From()); codeHash != emptyCodeHash && codeHash != (common.Hash{}) {
        return fmt.Errorf("%w: address %v, codehash: %s", ErrSenderNoEOA,
            st.msg.From().Hex(), codeHash)
    }
```

if an entry in state database has a code the `codeHash` variable will be non-empty (meaning it is a contract)

https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/a35b654f25fdac518d5775b55aa064025040b01a/core/state_transition.go#L252

Comment: That was just my wondering. Thank you!